# NextJS 14 Image - set background that will repeat for all sections

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, next-images

I have component Wrapper for the landing, I want to set background image that will repeat for all sections. With my code it will not repeat, could you help me?

```
const Wrapper = ({ children }: any) => (
  <div>
    <Image
      src="/assets/images/bg.svg"
      alt=""
      layout="fill"
      objectFit="cover"
    />
    {children}
  </div>
);

export default Wrapper;
```